# Why choose RDS/Aurora over EC2 instance on AWS, or choose CloudSQL over Compute Engine (VMs) for database server?

Tags: amazon-ec2, google-compute-engine, amazon-rds, google-cloud-sql, amazon-aurora

Recently, I've done some comparison between using Database as a service (e.g. CloudSQL on GCP and RDS/Aurora on AWS) and using VMs (e.g. Compute Engine on GCP and EC2 on AWS).

It turns out with the same type of machine/server, Database as a service is costing double as the price of setting us own VMs.

For example, on AWS, the r5.4xlarge EC2 instance costs $1.208/hour; while, the r5.4xlarge RDS costs $2.28/hour. Worse than that, Aurora costs $2.8/hour.

On GCP, the n1-high-mem-16 compute engine instance costs $686.33/month; while the n1-high-mem-16 CloudSQL costs $1387.98/month.

Why don't people spin up an EC2 instance or Compute Engine instance and set up their own MySQL?

It would be appreciated for you to write down your reasons of choosing the database as a service (CloudSQL or RDS or Aurora) than setting up a database on VMs?

Comment: Hello Steven. This question is not about programming but about server management. This means that this is the wrong stack exchange for it. It would be better if you were to move it to Server Fault. Good luck!

Comment: I suggest you ask this type of question on https://www.reddit.com/r/aws

Answer (score 1):

I can't generalise, but at one of the previous companies I worked for, they did a thourough analysis.

They included the cost of people needed to setup the database in high-available mode, added the continuous costs of backups and keeping up-to-date with security patches, which needed to be prepared in advance for every patch.

When you have a managed service it's an all-in-one package, and it was actually cheaper or less risky than having to hire a (part-time) DBA.

They also calculated in the adoption rate of innovation. When they needed e.g. MongoDB or Redis, a managed service could be adopted in a week instead of having to wait for several months for someone to analyse all risks and options to set it up in a High-Available state and coming up with a Security plan.